# Google chrome JS and CSS cache issue

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm facing an issue in Google Chrome when I write JS, CSS they doesn't show the result what should code give the output when I reboot the Google Chrome or clear the cache manually then they give the proper output
first code is here:

```
$(function () {
   alert("done");
});
```

They, show the correct result when I do some changing in code like:

```
$(function () {
   alert("Ok correctly working");
});
```

they do not show the proper result they show the last result done instead of Ok correctly working
also same issue in CSS.

Comment: *You should consider rephrasing your post as it isn't really clear what you want to achieve or expressing.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your code will not refresh in the browser due to google chrome caching the page and its resources, you could use the following:

Ctrl + Shift + Del - Clear your cached images and files.
Ctrl + Shift + R - to reload the page whilst ignoring cached files.

Comment: but it will logged out my all account any other proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+f5 to clear cache 
And then you will get the latest output

Comment: but it will logged out my all account any other proper solution?

Comment: i don`t think so , it will only refresh the cache ,

Comment: and your cookies will not be deleted in that case